# Using C# fetch Registered time of file (dll,exe,ocx)

Tags: c#, registry

I am installing an application, post installation i am performing few verification. One of which is to check the registered time and other is to check if the expected files list is registered.

I have list of files which should get registered and i have written code to verify that. But somehow i am not able to find a way to get the registered time[Date and Time] of the registered file.

Below is the code i wrote for fetching complete list of registry file and then run a loop of expected files on the obtained files to check if they are present or not.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string keyPath = @"SOFTWARE\Classes";
    //string keyPath = "InprocServer32";

    RegistryKey topRegKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Default).OpenSubKey(keyPath);

    GetAllKeys(topRegKey);
    int b = result.FindIndex(p => p.ToLower().Contains("MSCOMCT2.OCX".ToLower()));
}

public List<string> RegKeysList = new List<string>();

public static void GetAllKeys(RegistryKey regKey)
{
    if (regKey != null)
    {
        foreach (string key in regKey.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            GetAllKeys(regKey.OpenSubKey(key));
        }
        if (regKey.GetSubKeyNames().Length == 0)
        {
            try
            {
                result.Add(regKey.GetValue(string.Empty).ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
    }

}
```

I was able to find a C++ function RegQueryInfoKey function - ftLastWriteTime
to perform it(Didn't explore more on this). But i want to keep that as my last option.

Is there a way using C# to perform this. Am i missing something?

Comment: The RegistryKey wrapper class does not expose that info.  It is fairly doubtful you should take much stock in what you get back.  The registration for system components is rolled up in the Windows install, the installer does not explicitly register them.  If you get anything back at all then it is probably a date that represents when they built the installer in Redmond.  Especially unguessable today with the frequent Win10 updates.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? This approach is not good & its hard to see why its necessary: its the job of the installer to either install successfully or not at all.

Comment: I am doing a post installation verification for files, and for that i am checking version and timestamp. Which is helpful for troubleshooting build installation issues. I got way to check version but timestamp is something i am having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran RegDllView through command prompt and generated a file with all registered files using C#. Which had all registered files list with version,date,etc.

Through C# i copied RegDllView.exe to my server machine.

Followed by fetching required files list from the file. PFB working code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = "/C " + RegDllViewExePath + " /scomma " + RegDllOutputFilePath;
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
```